# React - State keeps same value even tho it is updated. (Inside function)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

so I have a function that runs every 5 seconds. Inside this function, I check if the state is null, to then set a value to it. The problem is that, every time the function run, it detects the state as null, even tho it is not null.

My code:

```
const [activeChat, setActiveChat] = useState(null)
const loadChats = async () => {
    await api.get('/v1/chat/chats')
        .then((res) => {
            if (activeChat === null) {
                if (res.data.chats.length > 0) {
                    setActiveChat(res.data.chats[0])
                }
            }
            setChats(res.data.chats)
            setLoading(false)
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            setLoading(false)
        })
}

useEffect(() => {
    loadChats()

    let interval = setInterval(() => {
        loadChats()
    }, 5000);

    return () => clearInterval(interval)

}, [])
```

the activeChat should be only set on the first load, if its not set yet, but it keeps detecting as null every time the function runs. Why does it keep detecting as null?

Obs: As I said, the state is really being set, as expected, so the problem is not with the response or something, i don't know what is happening..

Comment: That's because `loadChats` has a closure over the initial value of state, i.e. null. You didn't add `loadChats` in the dependency array, so `useEffect` only runs once.

Comment: @Yousaf It seems to have fixed my problem. But I didn't understand how it solves the problem. I mean, can you explain it to me?

Comment: Assuming that you understand [closures](https://yousaf.hashnode.dev/how-closures-work-in-javascript), everytime your component renders, a new instance of `loadChats` function is created that captures the current state value. As the initial value of the state is `null`, first instance of `loadChats` function (created during the first render) captures the `null` value. This instance is then passed to the `setInterval` function. As `setInterval` calls this instance of the function again and again, `loadChats` function continues to see the value of state that is captured, i.e `null`.

Comment: ..... You can fix the problem by ensuring that everytime your component re-renders, you pass a new instance of `loadChats` function that has captured the latest value of the state. This can be done by adding `loadChats` function in the dependency array of the `useEffect` hook.

Comment: @Yousaf how can I set your comment as the solution or something?

Comment: No need for that; this is a common problems many people face, specially people new to react. Your problem has been solved, enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

Inside setInterval or setTimeout, the state will NOT be changed even you have changed it inside the setInterval function. Try to create a timer using setInterval and you can see the state does not change inside it.

```
const [timer, setTimer] = useState(0);
useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(() => {
        console.log(timer); // remains the same (0) forever
        setTimer(timer + 1);
    }, 1000);
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
    console.log(timer); // this one should only change from 0 to 1, because timer always being set as 0 + 1;
}, [timer]);
```

You can create a ref for the chat object only for updating, and a state only for the chat display. Use the ref to keep track of the active chat, while using the state for UI display.